# Sprockets can't find my js files in a folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using the Asset Pipeline. I moved some of my JS into a "global" folder. Now sprockets can't find those files. Why? I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.

```
javscripts
|-- global
|   |-- someglobalstuff.js
|   |-- moreglobalstuff.js
|-- application.js
|-- homePage.js
|-- userPage.js
```

My application.js file has this:

```
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Is your directory really named `javscripts`? Or is it `javascripts`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix

```
require_tree ./global
```